# Nginx reverse proxy the Minio

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, minio

I am trying to put an Nginx in front of my Minio to serve the static files from the buckets. There are recipes both from [Minio](https://blog.min.io/enterprise-grade-cloud-storage-with-nginx-plus-and-minio/) and [Nginx](https://www.nginx.com/blog/enterprise-grade-cloud-storage-nginx-plus-minio/) sites but they never mention a very important concept: credentials. How can I set the simplest way that my nginx can log in to minio and fetch the items?
I know there are native codes like python or PHP clients but would like to do it with nginx as it is talking to an upstream web server. Any suggestion?

Comment: Huh? Why would nginx be providing credentials to minio? The user should be doing that.

Comment: Thanks Michael but there are obvious reasons to do so. Imagine a typical scenario where your site static object that accumulate throughout the time need being served. 
For security reasons the minio needs to be behind the nginx and again for security reasons minio only accepts the access with credentials.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method explained by:[tapos-ghosh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65353889/creating-public-access-to-minio-storage)
Where you will be making basically a bucket public through backend calls from Nginx..it works like a charm and great insight